# 2.3.3 Unable to Reindex Catalog Search: 'index catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1: does not support DELETE'

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, indexer

I have migrated from Magento1.9 to Magento2.3.3.

When running the reindexer command I got the following error: 
`index catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1: does not support DELETE (enabled=0) [ DELETE FROM catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 WHERE id > 0]`, all other indexes run just fine.

Error logs don’t appear to be throwing any errors related to this issue.

*UPDATE*
Thought the issue was related to DB Triggers having the wrong user, but all triggers are owned by the same user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. The change logs table for search was massive. Once I got that truncated the site was able to run the reindex with no more errors